# Image from layout not showing in some views

Tags: grails, layout, view, gsp

I have a problem with my layout or the views, I have a logo in the header of my layout, but everytime I go to certain view the logo does not show, it looks like a broken image. 
I have no idea why is this happenning but this is really annoying.

Comment: if you view the html source of the page, does the image url look correct?

Comment: yeah it's correct, it is the same url of the views where it works fine

Comment: If you try do directly access the image, it shows? If you put that in the view instead of layout it works?

Comment: If I put the image directly on the view it doesn't show either, I used `<img >` tag and nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [resource](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Tags/resource.html) tag like this:

```
<img src="${resource(dir:'PATH_TO_FILE', file:'FILE_NAME')}">
```

Comment: Using resource rather than the other way around worked, weird. Thanks